# dealing with authentication in asp.net using membership

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sqlmembershipprovider

Ok, here is the problem:

I have two sites: www.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com (fake site names) which suppose to share authentication.
The login page is on www.mysite.com/login/login.aspx

Now, the blog website has web.config with following authentication section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="50000000" 
   loginUrl="http://www.mysite.com/login/login.aspx"
   defaultUrl="~/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Now I hit `blog.mysite.com/andrey/page.aspx` and it redirects me to login page which is on `www` site. The real problem is that "reditect" query string will only contain relative page url (`andrey/page.aspx`), so when I login it will try to redirect me to `www.mysite.com/andrey/page.aspx`, not `blog.mysite.com/andrey/page.aspx` where i started so of course everything fails.

Is there a way to tell Membership object to put the full path into "redirect" query string parameter when it bounces to login page?

Thanks!
Andrey

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each domain has its own web.config, I think this might work.

1) Create a login page for both www.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com
2) Point both to the same membership database
3) Make sure both have the same membership applicationName attribute set:

```
<membership><providers><add applicationName="mySite">
```

4) Make sure both have the same forms name set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"><forms  name="mySite">
```

This should ensure that both sites use the same membership database and the same authentication cookie, but they'll use their individual login pages and so the return url should be fine.

---

Can you call the [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) and manually redirect to the http referrer?

---

I just saw this in the documentation for [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5z1yty.aspx)

> By default, the ReturnUrl variable
>   must refer to a page within the
>   current application. If ReturnUrl
>   refers to a page in a different
>   application or on a different server,
>   the  RedirectFromLoginPage method
>   redirects to the URL in the 
>   DefaultUrl property. If you want to
>   allow redirects to a page outside the
>   current application, you must set the 
>   EnableCrossAppRedirects property to
>   true using the enableCrossAppRedirects
>   attribute of the  forms configuration
>   element. Security noteSecurity Note:
>
> Setting the EnableCrossAppRedirects
>   property to true to allow
>   cross-application redirects is a
>   potential security threat. When
>   cross-application redirects are
>   allowed, your site is vulnerable to
>   malicious Web sites that use your
>   login page to convince your Web site
>   users that they are using a secure
>   page on your site. To improve security
>   when using cross-application
>   redirects, you should override the
>   RedirectFromLoginPage method to allow
>   redirects only to approved Web sites.

Does messing with that property help at all?

Comment: Well, I still wanted to have one place to login into the portal. Any ideas how to control RedirectUrl?

All I could go with so far, is to reverse engineer and rebrand FormsAuthenticationModule class, make changes so it puts the whole URL into redirectUrl, and use that module instead of Microsoft's FormsAuthenticationModule class.

Comment: No, I don't know of any way to do that. 
If both login pages looked exactly the same except for the URL, and each could log you in to both sites, that doesn't really seem that different from a user experience from "one place to login into the portal" to me.

Comment: Agreed, but I actually have 7 sites and supporting login page for every one of them is an unnecessary overhead if it can be avoided. 
I guess I'll have to rewrite FormsAuthenticationModule class to fit my needs...

Comment: I actually don't think that an authentication cookie created on a 3rd level domain blogs.mysite.com would be available from the second level domain www.mysite.com, so user woudl have to re-login when going to www page if logged in to blogs originally, which is not acceptable.